# Data label Google spreadsheet Column chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a column chart in Google spreadsheet, but it is not showing data label explicitly.

[image: screenshot]

I need data value to be shown on top of each bar of column chart. Currently, that is showing only as tool tip, but I require it to be always visible.

I have not used any script just created it directly, please provide some way either by script/direct to implement data labels. only direct / apps script but no java script as I only need to view it on my spreadsheet.

here is link of sheet:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a95DrTeLA52Xmycq3IUlWgfqASQWJQla7xEXx5-KWGE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Show your code. There are several ways to implement charts.

Comment: @Mogsdad I have not used any script just created it directly, please provide some way either by script/direct to implement data labels. only direct / apps script but no java script as I only need to view it on my spreadsheet.

Comment: You're going to have to explain your question better, to show exactly what you mean. Pictures would help immensely. At this time, it's not clear what your problem is. (For example - have you tried right-clicking on the chart, and setting the Axis titles?)

Comment: @Mogsdad I need data value to be shown on top of each bar of column chart. Axix title is not solving it. view image as below link                                   https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10206793982756507&set=a.2549242818734.144291.1483753528&type=1&theater

Comment: I've updated your question with the additional info you provided. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this nice presentation

Comment: It would be helpful (for us) if you can add a sample (shared) spreadsheet with the chart. The answer can be viewed then and there.

Comment: @Vasim Please find link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a95DrTeLA52Xmycq3IUlWgfqASQWJQla7xEXx5-KWGE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have found the solution by now but just in case it might be helpful to others, here's my response.

Your sharing of sheet was useful in helping you with your question. Here are the steps to get the values for the data labels on the top of your columns.

- Right click on the chart.
- Click on Advanced Edit. (This will open a new window named "Chart Editor")
- Click on "Customization" tab.
- Drag the bar and keep going down until you see "Data Labels" with a drop down below it.
- Click on the drop down. (This will open a list of options)
- Choose "value" from this list of options.
- Click "Update" and you'll see the change in your graph.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I did this, but it still wouldn't show any Data Labels. In fact, *nothing* changed.

Comment: Having this same problem. Data Labels are set to value in my Column chart, but nothing displays on the chart. Columns are showing a count of occurrences of various values in a single column.

Comment: I too have run into this and what I've noticed is that if you choose to "Aggregate column X", currently under the "Charts types" tab, then the values will disappear.  The bar chart will properly aggregate the values, reset grid lines and set the bar heights properly, but it seems to forget to pass the new aggregated values to the data labels.  Lame.

Answer (score -3):

I figured out a solution. If you create a pivot table and graph that data, the values will show.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to add some steps to this answer, as @Gitanjali did.