# Insert data value labels in Geo Chart in google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I want to insert the Data Label (names of country) & Data values on the Geochart viz in Google sheets. Currently I can see details only when I hover the mouse above the bubbles in the map. I want to show labels like in this pic [I want the labels like this - name & value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsRp.png) Please check the link to the image

Is there a code or any way to do it? There is NO direct way in the "customize" tab in the chart editor.

Comment: Did you already try the solution in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444309/data-label-google-spreadsheet-column-chart)? Also, try to check this [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)